# Обработка "неправильного" содержимого первой строки файла и возникающие проблемы с "правильным" содержимым. C++

Tags: c++

Добрый день.
Есть файл в следующем формате:

```
n
string1
string2
string3
```

n - целое положительное число (число строк ниже).
Проверка на то, является ли n символом получилась следующим образом:

```
if (!(input >> numOfStrings) || numOfStrings < 1)
{
    std::cout << "First symbol in file has to be an integer number (number of strings)" << std::endl;
    numOfStrings = 0;   
}

std::string readFromFile;
std::vector<std::string> arrStrings;
arrStrings.resize(numOfStrings);

while (std::getline(input, readFromFile))
    arrStrings.push_back(readFromFile);

printArr(arrStrings);
```

Собственно, почему:

1. Если первая строка это НЕ число, то последующий код "пропускается" и в консоль идёт только предупреждение, а вектор остаётся пустым:

   First symbol in file has to be an integer number (number of strings)
2. Если первая строка положительный символ, то откуда-то берётся пустая строка и размер вектора - 4, а не 3 и эта пустая строка выводится перед всеми. Откуда она берётся и как от неё избавиться?
3. Как не дать ему считывать следующие строки, если первое число отрицательное? (Хотел сделать это через resize, но вектор сам себе выделяет память)

Comment: В реальности делается немного иначе. Обьявляется массив байт, туда файл считывается порциями по 4кбайт и парсится. Данный подход проще, и чаще всего даётся в учебных заведениях. Если это не критично - оставьте как есть.

Comment: "вектор сам себе выделяет память" - это как это "сам"? Вы же сами открытым текстом явно вызываете `arrStrings.resize(numOfStrings);`. Что по вашему должно было произойти в этом случае, если `numOfStrings` отрицательно?

Comment: Если numOfStrings отрицательно, то в if он зануляется, и ресайз происходит на нуль. Но push_back так и так загоняет строку в вектор.

Comment: @Sotnik: Так `push_back` по определению "сам" выделяет память. Никакого сюрприза в этом нет. Тут наоборот неясно, зачем понадобился ваш `resize`, который просто создает в векторе пустые строки. `resize` был бы нужен, если бы вы записывали строки через `[]`. А у вас - `push_back`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Если первая строка это НЕ число, то последующий код "пропускается" и в консоль идёт только предупреждение, а вектор остаётся пустым

После того, как вы попытались считать из потока не то, что там на самом деле есть, он переходит в состояние [`fail`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/fail/). В этом состоянии из потока больше ничего прочитать нельзя. Чтобы перевести поток назад в состояние [`good`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/good/) воспользуйтесь методом [`clear`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/clear/).

```
if (!(input >> numOfStrings) || numOfStrings < 1)
{
    input.clear();
    //...
}
```

---

> 2. Если первая строка положительный символ, то откуда-то берётся пустая строка и размер вектора - 4, а не 3 и эта пустая строка
>      выводится перед всеми. Откуда она берётся и как от неё избавиться?

Тут сразу несколько проблем.

Во-первых, использование пары [`resize`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/resize/) + [`push_back`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/push_back/). Когда вы делаете `resize(3)` в векторе становится три объекта. `push_back`, в свою очередь, тоже добавляет объекты в вектор:

```
std::vector<std::string> strings;
strings.resize(3);

std::cout << strings.size() << std::endl; //3

for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i){
    strings.push_back("str");
}

std::cout << strings.size() << std::endl; //6

printArr(strings) //["", "", "", "str", "str", "str"]
```

Во-вторых, ваше `numOfStrings` никак не влияет на количество прочитанных строк. Вы читаете весь файл до конца.

Правильно можно сделать по-разному. При помощи `resize`:

```
std::vector<std::string> arrStrings; //То же самое что 
arrStrings.resize(numOfStrings);     //std::vector<std::string> arrStrings(numOfStrings);

for(std::string &str : arrStrings){
    if(!std::getline(input, str)){
        std::cout << "Not enough lines in file" << std:: endl;
        return;
    }
}
```

При помощи `push_back`:

```
std::vector<std::string> arrStrings;
for(int i = 0; i < numOfStrings; ++i){
    std::string str;
    if(!std::getline(input, str)){
        std::cout << "Not enough lines in file" << std:: endl;
        return;
    }

    arrStrings.push_back(str);
}
```

---

> 3. Как не дать ему считывать следующие строки, если первое число отрицательное?

```
if(numOfStrings < 0){
    return;
}
```

Comment: `int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
 std::ifstream input(argv[1]);`
А не подскажите, почему вот такой код выдаёт исключение " Недопустимый параметр был передан функции, для которой недопустимые параметры вызывают неустранимую ошибку." при компиляции и как с этим бороться? Спасибо!

Comment: @Sotnik, `#include <fstream>`?

Comment: fstream подключена

Comment: @Sotnik, Сделайте воспроизводимый пример. У меня [все нормально](http://cpp.sh/7y4bg)

Comment: вот https://pp.userapi.com/c841620/v841620225/5d41d/RMxmETNLGUk.jpg

Comment: @Sotnik, если у вас `argc` больше 1, то с точки зрения языка, все нормально. В таком случае все вопросы к детищу майкрософта. Я им ни разу не пользовался